# Can I read data from a Firebase database in real time and have it constantly updating in an Android App?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi

I am making an Android app in Android Studio, and I am using Firebase for authentication and the real-time database features. On top of this I am connecting these to a Raspberry Pi with a temp sensor and light sensor. Is there a way for me to read in the current temperature from the Pi to my app? With maybe a refresh every 5 seconds? I have guessed that I could write data from the Pi in to the database and then access it via the app.

Any suggestions / help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the data can be kept in sync using Firebase real-time database listeners. Refer this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) for information on the listeners.

Answer (score 0):

When your app is connected to your Firebase you don't have to wait 5 sec to see the change, but insistently see it happening.

Your phone will have a listener at a location on the Firebase, and when RPi writes to that location, and if you have the app open and listening, you will see the change as soon as it completes on Firebase.

Check this 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-changed

Comment: Cheers, I'll take a look!